# Why Debug.Writeline is printing my message in reverse

Tags: c#, debugging

I write something like this:

```
Debug.WriteLine("RefKey value was {0}", refKey);
```

And then in output window I see:

**200002V0dH: refInterfaceKey was {0}**

Why is it kind of printing it right to left?

Comment: @CodeCaster small correction. It isn't `(object,string)` rather `(string,string)` as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190153%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of this function is `WriteLine(string message,string category)`. This means that it will show your category and then, your message. For instance, category could be `TRACE` or `DEBUG`.

I think that what you are looking for is `string.Format`. You should have

```
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("RefKey value was {0}", refKey))
```